# What is the mathematical definition of a function that gives the rank order of the components of a vector?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, vectors, definition

Mathematically, how can a function $f()$ be defined such that it takes an N-dimensional vector $\vec v$ and gives the rank ordering $\vec r$ of the components of $\vec v$? The components of $\vec r$ are some permutation of $[0, 1, 2 ... N-1]$ for an N-dimensional vector.

$$
f(\vec v) = \vec r \\
f([1,2,3]) = [0,1,2] \\
f([6,-2,4]) = [2,0,1]
$$

If the component values $v_a$ and $v_b$ of $\vec v$ are have the same value, the lower rank order $R$ is assigned to the lower index $r_a$ of $\vec r$, and $r_b=R+1$ where $a<b$.

$$
f([0,0,0]) = [0,1,2] \\
f([1,-1,-1,1]) = [2,0,1,3] \\
f([0,0,-1,0,1]) = [1,2,0,3,4]
$$

I am also interested in the mathematical definition of a function $g()$ that gives the rank ordering of the absolute value of the components of $\vec v$.

$$
g([1,-1,-1,1]) = [0,1,2,3] \\
g([0,0,-1,0,1]) = [0,1,3,2,4]
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematical definition"?  As far as mathematics is concerned, what you have just written is a fine definition (though it is possible to make it a bit more precise).

Comment: If possible, I am looking for something formulaic as opposed to a verbal description.  Ultimately I want to calculate the derivative of a function that uses $f()$.

Comment: Also, I have a feeling I may have described something that already has a name and a standard definition.  If that is the case, I would like to know what the standard name is.

Comment: Any such formula would be *extremely* difficult to use for differentiation purposes, except on the connected regions where the order is fixed, where the derivative is obvious anyway -- so much so that the question seems moot.

Comment: You could define it easily recursively. But it is kind of over the top and might obscure the idea. Also, you need to specify what to with duplicates, as otherwise it is ambiguous and not a function. Much hassle for nothing.

Comment: $f()$ splits the N-space into N! regions.  $g()$ splits it into N! or 2N! regions depending on how you look at it.  Not at all continuous and not useful for differentiation if used directly.  This is not a problem for my application because $f(\vec v)$ is fed into other other functions and the whole thing is ultimately multiplied by a continuous function that is zero on the boundary.  There are other contributing factors, so the overall derivative is generally not zero.  I'm just trying to take it one function at a time.

Comment: I would be happy to see this defined as a recursive function.  The verbal description addresses duplicates.  $f([0,0,0])=[0,1,2]$